# Cache identity helper in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, caching, blazor

I am building a Blazor Server application and I have a few Web API controllers where each method needs to verify the identity of the caller.

Each caller, passes UserId and GroupId via a JWT and a targetUserId as call parameter. I then check if this User has permission to fetch data for users that are in the same group as the caller. If the caller is in the same group, the data should be returned.

This means that in the beginning of each Web API call I would need to do something like:

```
if (Database.GetGroup(targetUserId) == GroupId)
{
    return data;
}
```

I am imagining that this is not efficient since for each GetGroup method I would actually need several SQL joins to achieve this. And since my tables will update quite frequently I am worried all these group lookups will generate deadlocks.

My idea now is that since the User actually never changes group. How can I, when my application starts, build a List<> of all users and their groups, similar to a cache? That lives for the whole execution of my Blazor Server app? Then I could do:

```
if (GroupIdCache(targetUserId) == GroupId)
{
    return data;
}
```

If a user was added after this list was built, the group would not be found and first I would try to refresh the list and if not found then return an error.

An alternative way would be to add for all my SQL statements throughout the application " .. AND WHERE GroupId = @GroupId" but I am thinking that checking the security constraints before even passing SQL code is a better alternative. Plus that I would need to join with that table everywhere.

Comment: Take a look at this : [Resource-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: I do not see how I could use that to resolve my issue.

Comment: If your permission data is user wise then you should fetch data after user login and clear this cache once user logout.

Comment: If you want to maintain a global cache for all users, then I will recommend creating one background job while handle Redis sync logic (Removing and adding new user)